# php based game - castle layout

Tags: php

I am making a PHP-based RPG, city-building game. My idea is to create a 9X9 grid for a castle layout with the center 3X3 being the inner castle and upon clicking on that section they will see an 6X6 grid of the inner castle. The players will also be able to acquire tiles of the outer grid turning them into inner castle. Every tile is able to be built upon. What would the best way to represent this in the database, taking scalability into account?

The only approach I have come up so far is a 3-column table with (idcastle, Y, X), X being a string of 18 numbers. I would use substr to see if there is a building on that tile.
However, I think that I will run into scalability issues if there are a lot of castles (since each castle requires 18 rows).

Comment: The RPG tag is for a programming language. This question probably belongs on gamedevelopment.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends how you query the database. I would suggest dynamically making your id so it was 
castleid_x_y_z that way you are only querying against the primary key making it very quick.

Plus use something like redis to handle it as it generally is limited only by network speed. If you have too many castles you would just push people to a second server. You don't even need to worry about scaling as you wouldn't split 1 castle over two servers

Comment: Sorry can you explein the castleid_x_y_z part better?

Comment: Instead of using an auto_incrementing ID you are better off setting your own so if caste 1 had a block at 1 x-axis, 1 y-axis and 1 z-axis its id would be 1_1_1_1 that way when you query the database you already know all the info so you join in it your application and then do SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = "1_1_1_1" and you will get better performance then WHERE castleid =1 AND x =1 AND y =1 AND z = 1

Comment: so for an 10X10 grid i have 100 rows?

Comment: Depends on if you need to put any data with the individual blocks otherwise you can just make it two columns id and a data column like 1010011010010101010101010010010101010101111001010 to represent the taken blocks